# Access news feed from Facebook using the iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to implement Facebook in my iPhone app and I have successfully authorized the app in the application delegate as shown in Facebook's guide.
Now I can easily use Facebook around my application using the code below.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
facebook = [appDelegate facebook];
```

I would like to get the user's News Feed but when doing so using the following code I get an error.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andDelegate:self];
```

The error is:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
>
> ```
> {
>     error = {
>         message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
>         type = OAuthException;
>     };
> }
> ```

I have read that the News Feed should be retrieved using `me/home`. The session seems to be active as I have no problem getting the user's wall posts using `me/feed`.

Does anyone know why I can't get the user's news feed? I have added the `read_stream` permission and when I log into my Facebook account I see that my application is registered as being able to read my news feed.

> **This app can:** Access posts in my News Feed

Comment: Any idea how to get newsfeeds of specific object like one of your friend's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=367264#p367264) on [Facebooks Developer Forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net) indicates that this is a problem on Facebook's part.